# Incrementing number in variable ($_POST)

Tags: php, variables, post, while-loop, increment

I cant find working solution for my problem. I want edit this line:

```
$variable_1 = (isset($_POST["variable_1"])) ? strip_tags(trim($_POST["variable_1"])) : false;
```

I need cycle this line for `$variable_1` up to `$variable_60`. Can anyone help me, how make it with incremental number? Thanks.

Comment: Why not using a array as target as well? You can use a for loop with loop var as index.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$data=$_POST;
for ($i=1; $i <=60 ; $i++) { 
    $data['variable_'.$i]=isset($_POST['variable_'.$i])? strip_tags(trim($_POST['variable_'.$i])) : false;
}
```